# Boot loop after doing 'Clear TPM' by mistake in BIOS

Tags: boot, laptop, bios, battery, tpm

I was trying to disable 'Secure boot' on my brand new laptop and I pressed enter by mistake while on a field that was named something like 'Clear TPM'. My computer then shut down and now it is looping on boot.

I press the power button, power is OK but then I have a black screen for 2 seconds and the computer shuts down completely. This keeps going in a loop until I press the Power button for a long time to cut the power.
I can not even access the BIOS. I tried to reset the battery by pressing inserting a small pointy object in the hole with a battery logo under the laptop as the support suggested but it did not work.

Is it bad? Did I something wrong/stupid?

I am currently on business trip abroad and I can not send it to the manufacturer from here.

The laptop is an ACER Spin 5 (SP515-51GN).

Comment: What's the make and model?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT It is ACER Spin 5 (SP515-51GN)

Comment: Do you have anything enabled that requires your TPM to function, e.g. BitLocker?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator No, It is a personal laptop. I only set a Supervisor password in the BIOS to be able to disable 'Secure boot'

Comment: Can you try starting the system without the hard disk connected? Any difference?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator I will try later today, i'm currently at work. Why do you think it could have something to do with the hard disk ?

Comment: I can't see clearing the TPM causing this issue. Even if it did cause a problem, you would see a message about a failure to boot, or some indication the operating system is trying to boot. Your system sounds as if it is not posting at all. This sounds like a complete hardware failure. Any link to what you were doing in the BIOS is coincidental I would say. Try removing and reseating the RAM or operating with only one module if you have 2.

Comment: @Appleoddity I don't understand either why this would cause a hardware failure... I tried removing the ram and reinserting it and then boot, same problem...

Comment: I don't have a *specific* reason to believe the HDD is at fault. However, the basic process of getting your laptop to do something other than what it's currently doing is to change those variables involved in the POST process completing normally. When a change elicits a different response, it will serve as a clue to what's keeping it from POSTing. The HDD (as well as RAM as suggested, CMOS reset as you've done, etc.) is one of the few things that can keep a POST from completing...say if it's not fully seated or has experienced an electrical malfunction.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator I understand, thank you for the explanation. I just want to know and understand how it ended up like this. Also, at this point do you think it is the kind of problem I can fix easily without damaging my laptop or should I just sent it to Acer support ?

Comment: The answer to your question depends on what's wrong. I don't know what's wrong so I can't properly answer that question.